# PHP/Wordpress: Why is this echo always loading in the same spot no matter what?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I am extending someone else's plugin. He has an action hook in the function he uses to initialize the plugin. It doesn't matter if I put `echo nl2br("this is located OVER the do action anspress loaded. \n");` **BELOW** or **ABOVE** the line `do_action('anspress_loaded');` - the line always get's echo'd out **ABOVE** another line I have being echo'd inside the other code loaded on that hook. Why is this? It's probably not TREMENDOUSLY important but I'm just curious....(noob here). Any idea?

**this initializes the plugin**

```
        /**
         * Initializes the plugin by setting localization, hooks, filters, and administrative functions.
         *
         * @return instance
         */
        public static function instance() {

            if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) && ! (self::$instance instanceof self) ) {
                self::$instance = new self();
                self::$instance->setup_constants();
                self::$instance->actions = array();
                self::$instance->filters = array();

                add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( self::$instance, 'load_textdomain' ) );

                add_action( 'bp_loaded', array( self::$instance, 'bp_include' ) );

                global $ap_classes;
                $ap_classes = array();

                self::$instance->includes();

                self::$instance->ajax_hooks();
                self::$instance->site_include();

                self::$instance->anspress_forms         = new AnsPress_Process_Form();
                self::$instance->anspress_query_filter  = new AnsPress_Query_Filter();
                self::$instance->anspress_cpt           = new AnsPress_PostTypes();
                self::$instance->anspress_reputation    = new AP_Reputation();

                /*
                 * ACTION: anspress_loaded
                 * Hooks for extension to load their codes after AnsPress is leaded
                 */
                echo nl2br("this is located OVER the do action anspress loaded. \n");
                do_action('anspress_loaded');


                self::$instance->setup_hooks();
            }

            return self::$instance;
        }
```

**this might be important:**

```
        /**
         * Register the filters and actions with WordPress.
         */
        private function setup_hooks() {
            foreach ( $this->filters as $hook ) {
                add_filter( $hook['hook'], array( $hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ), $hook['priority'], $hook['accepted_args'] );
            }

            foreach ( $this->actions as $hook ) {
                add_action( $hook['hook'], array( $hook['component'], $hook['callback'] ), $hook['priority'], $hook['accepted_args'] );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it actually above it in the source or just when you view it in the browser? Some CSS could be causing it to show up above it, especially if the `anspress_loaded` content is floated left or right.